# Apache Cassandra - How to stress IO

Tags: io, cassandra, benchmarking, stress-testing

I have been working with Cassandra for a bit now, and have followed the benchmarking tips found at the following link:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-not-to-benchmark-cassandra

I have 4 nodes running Cassandra, and 2 different nodes feeding the cluster with the native benchmarking tool 'cassandra-stress'. I understand because of the LSM nature of Cassandra writes that they are hardly ever going to be IO bound however on reads I expected I would be able to stress the cluster in such a way that it would be IO bound. So far I have been unable to get even close to making the IO the bottleneck.

I have increased the number of concurrent write/reads; I have increased stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec so it wouldn't throttle; I have increased the number of cassandra-stress clients by a factor of 3 (this just made it more CPU bound).

My setup on each Cassandra node is a separate HDD for the commitLogs, and I have 10-drive DAS set up for the data storage. I have monitored the IO with Linux's iostat utility, and I can never get the utilization of the drives to be anywhere near 100%. Further I have decreased the allowable memory available to Cassandra thinking that would force it to flush more often. The following is how I am launching the write stress test:

cassandra-stress -d 192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2 -n 20000000 -t 400 -f 20million_write_1 & cassandra-stress -d 192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2 -n 20000000 -t 400 -f 20million_write_2 & cassandra-stress -d 192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2 -n 20000000 -t 400 -f 20million_write_3 &

And the following is how I am launching the read stress test:

cassandra-stress -d 192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2 -n 20000000 -t 400 -f 20million_read_1 -o read & cassandra-stress -d 192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2 -n 20000000 -t 400 -f 20million_read_2  -o read & cassandra-stress -d 192.168.2.1,192.168.2.2 -n 20000000 -t 400 -f 20million_read_3 -o read &

I am doing this from the 2 external nodes which are feeding the 4-node Cassandra cluster.

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can effectively stress the IO, and make it IO bound? Or possibly what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you for your time, and patience.

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

A separate commitlog disk and 10 data disks.. You are "Doing It Right".

You could try mixed read&write workloads with larger values to try to increase overall I/O, but you may again find this works fine on your hardware choice.